# Facing issues with StatbombR library

Tags: r, data-analysis

Pretty new to R and analytics would really appreciate some help with this.
Whenever I try and select data, even tho I go through the PDF as it says from the StatbombR website.

https://statsbomb.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Working-with-R.pdf

Gives me the following error.
Error in if (MatchesDF == "ALL") { : the condition has length > 1

The code I've been using :

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("remotes")
devtools::install_github("statsbomb/StatsBombR")
devtools::install_github("FCrSTATS/SBpitch")
install.packages("SDMTools", "1.1-221")
library(SBpitch)
library(StatsBombR)

Comp <- FreeCompetitions()
Matches <- FreeMatches(Comp)
StatsBombData <- StatsBombFreeEvents(MatchesDF = Matches, Parallel = T)

Comp <- Comp %>%
  filter(competition_id==37 & season_name=="2020/2021")
```

Comment: have you included all of your code? There's no `if (MatchesDF == "ALL")` in your code

Comment: but in general, if MatchesDF is a dataframe, then it's not a length one object you can evaluate as being "ALL". Chances are, you meant to use ifelse, which is vectorised

Comment: Hey Mark Yeah that's the entire code I'm working from Statsbombs own pdf guide I attached a link to. I'm not sure what's causing the issue

Here's the code again

library(StatsBombR)

library(tidyverse)

Comp <- FreeCompetitions() %>%
  filter(competition_id==37 & season_name=="2020/2021")

Matches <- FreeMatches(Comp)

StatsBombData <- StatsBombFreeEvents(MatchesDF = Matches, Parallel = T)

Comment: adding code as a comment is generally speaking a bad idea. You can edit your question if you want to add new code

Comment: you might find this thread handy: https://community.rstudio.com/t/help-with-statsbomb-free-football-data/139624/6

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the link seems like it does pull with that string somehow.. Thanks for your help.